# How to set div height auto with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

i have found a code which is perfect for my work. I want to set div height auto in jquery 8 no line. please see the  link.

http://jsfiddle.net/alexis_tondelier/Gf2dv/

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-overlay"></div>        
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

> jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $active,
    togglerSelector = '.item',
    toggledSelector = '.item-overlay',
    $items = $(togglerSelector),
    animationDuration = 300,
    activeClassName = 'active',
    activeStyle = {height: 300},
    notActiveStyle = {height: 0},
    hideActive = function() {
        $active && $active
            .stop()
            .animate(notActiveStyle, function() {
                $(this).removeClass(activeClassName).hide();
            });    
        $active = void 0;        
    },
    showActive = function($element) {
        $element && ($active = $element)
            .stop()
            .show()
            .animate(activeStyle)
            .addClass(activeClassName)
    };

$items.on('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $overlay = $this.children(toggledSelector),
        theSame = $overlay.is($active);
    hideActive();
    theSame || showActive($overlay);
});
$(this).on('click', function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target),
        isOutClick = !$target.closest(togglerSelector).length;
    isOutClick && hideActive();
});
```

});

Thanks....

Comment: What are you asking for?  Div height auto no line?  What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Is this what you want?  http://jsfiddle.net/Gf2dv/13/

Comment: Hi, Solomon. I have given a link . In that code of jquery line number 8 has set the height attribute to 300px. I want to set this as auto. Am i clear?

Comment: If you want to set to auto, remove that entire line and it will be set to auto!  You have nothing in there for content, so nothing will show.  I provided a link on how to accomplish this already to a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks.........your fiddle is  working nice that's i want. what changes did you make in this code?

Comment: I removed the entire line #8 and added in some content to show that it works, that's it!